# Prove the modular congruence with prime factors of $3^p-1$ and $5^p-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I came up with a theorem of similar in relation to one of the theorems on Mersenne Numbers $2^n-1$ shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

If $p$ is an odd prime, then every odd prime factor $q$ dividing $3^p-1$ is congruent to $±1$ $\pmod {12}$ and congruent to $1$ $\pmod {2p}$.

Similarily, If $p$ is an odd prime, then every odd prime factor $q$ dividing $5^p-1$ is congruent to $±1$ $\pmod {10}$ and congruent to $1$ $\pmod {2p}$.

Can anyone show the complete proof that these generalized theorems is true? Thanks for proof.

Comment: Would be nice to see a couple of examples of some value of $p$ and corresponding values of $q$. It will probably require you to do a bit of research, and perhaps see a pattern (if you do that for more than one value of $p$). And if you don't see the pattern, then at least we'll know that you've tried, and feel more enthusiastic investigating it ourselves.

Comment: The one with $2^p-1$ is the same as above except with $±1$ $\pmod 8$, and I did provide a source to this theorem, but I would appreciate that someone prove these, because this is not the same as the one with base $2$.

Comment: Some factorizations: $3^3-1$ $=$ $2*13$, $13$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod 12$, and $1$ $\pmod 3$, $5^3-1$ $=$ $2*2*31$, $31$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod 10$ and $1$ $\pmod 3$. Larger: $3^11-1$ $=$ $2*23*3851$, both odd prime factors are congruent to $11$ $\pmod 12$, $1$ $\pmod 11$, $5^11-1$ $=$ $2*2*12207031$, the odd prime factor is $1$ $\pmod 10$ and $1$ $\pmod 11$. Just some few examples of these conjectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an odd prime $q$ divides $3^p-1$ then we have 
$$
3^p \equiv 1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ q.
$$
This gives $\mathrm{ord}_q(3)=p$. By Fermat's little theorem, 
$$p=\mathrm{ord}_q(3)|q-1.$$
Thus, $q\equiv 1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ p$. Since we are assuming that $q$ is odd, $q-1$ must be even. Thus, $2p |q-1$.

Passing on to Legendre symbol, we have
$$
\left(\frac{3^p}q\right)=1.
$$
Since we are assuming that $p$ is odd, 
$$
\left(\frac{3^p}q\right)=\left(\frac{3 }q\right)^p=\left(\frac{3}q\right) = 1.
$$
The quadratic reciprocity law gives
$$
\left(\frac 3q \right) = (-1)^{\frac{q-1}2} \left(\frac q3\right)=1.
$$
This gives $q\equiv \pm 1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ 12$.

The $5^p-1$ case can be treated the same way.